# How to call useEffect after updating state in a component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I am having a little trouble calling a useEffect using a setstate that I passed as a prop to a child component. I am not sure this is the way to do this.

The code goes something like this:

```
const Parent = () => {
const [state, setState] = useState()
useEffect(() => {
    console.log ('state updated');
}, [state])

return (
    <>
    <Child state={state} setState = {setState}/>
    </>
)}

const Child = (props) => {
const update = () => {
    props.setState("updated");
}
return(
    <>
    <button onClick={update}></button>
    </>
)}
```

In this case, I expect the useEffect to run when the button is clicked but it does not. How do I fix it or is there a better way of doing this. Note that the two components are different files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `setState` as a prop to `Child` component. Previously you passed only state prop.

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log ('state updated');
    }, [state])

    return (
        <>
            <Child setState={setState}/>
        </>
    )
}

const Child = (props) => {
    const update = () => {
        props.setState("updated");
    }

    return(
        <>
            <button onClick={update}></button>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I updated the code and it's still not calling the useEffect. Is there any other reasons that could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code here https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-cherry-n5ygr?file=/src/App.js and it works as expected.

`useEffect` is called only once because subsequent states have the same value 'updated'. Please note that useEffect is also called when the component is mounted so you should expect to see 2 console.log after you've clicked the button.

Comment: I see. I think there must be something else that is messing with my code and preventing the useEffect to run then. Thank you for your insights!

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my own problem:
There wasn't anything wrong with my code above. However, in my codebase, I didn't realize that I changed the value of the object but not the reference. Now that I assigned a new reference for each value change, it works perfectly.